# Getting Error "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, database, connection, database-connection

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Database.

This is my script:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import pysftp
import pyodbc



sq_conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=someserver.com/;"
                        "Database=SomeDB;"
                        "uid=myid;pwd=password;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

    
print("Starting to load data")
        
sql = "select top 100 * from table"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, sq_conn)
df.head(3)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> sq_conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and configured it in /etc/odbcinst.ini? SNC dates from SQL Server 2005-2012 era, though. Consider installing [ODBC 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) on Linux for newer development.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did install ODBD17 for MacOS. It still gives me the same error. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: i changed the Driver to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Now I get this error:

'pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')'

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice this before... do you really have `http://someserver.com/` in your connection string? Try using just `someserver.com` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't have http in my actual script, I fixed the question above. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It was a SQL Server Access issue. It is resolved now. All I had to do is get a user created under my name for that server, I was trying to use my windows credentials in the above script before which obviously was failing.

Thank you for all the help.